# i want to retrieve image in this way but it wont

Tags: c#, mysql, database, image

I cant retrieve image from database

```
byte[] image = (byte[])(reader["Can_Pic"]);
if (image == null)
{
    Picture.Image = null;
}
else
{
    Memory Stream stream = new Memory Stream(image);
    Picture.Image = System.Drawing.Image.From Stream(stream);
}
```

Comment: what's the `space` character between `From` and `Stream`? in last line of the code you shown

Comment: when i ask question . it's become error . so i add it space so that i can post my codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this :-)

```
 Byte[] image=(Byte[])(reader["Can_Pic"]); 

    if (image.Length == 0)
    {
        Picture.Image = null;
    }
    else
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
        Picture.Image = new Bitmap(stream);
    }
```